# How to read a line from a file into an ansible variable

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to read the database password on a remote host from the file `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`. Format of the file is below. Is there a way to parse out the `password` field so I can drop a mysql user via Ansible?

```
# Automatically generated for Debian scripts. DO NOT TOUCH!
[client]
host     = localhost
user     = root
password = 5unnyv4l3
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysql_upgrade]
host     = localhost
user     = root
password = 5unnyv4l3
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
basedir  = /usr
```

Answer (score 16):

It looks like the 'slurp' module will work for your requirements:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/slurp_module.html

```
- name: extract password from file
  slurp:
    src: /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
register: mypasswordfile

- name: Set User Password
  user: name=newUser
    password="{{ passwordfile['content'] | b64decode | regex_findall('password = \"(.+)\"') | first }}"
```

*Edited after testing and fixing.*

Comment: Uh..That second task actually creates a new user account (typo with `passwordfile` too), but I think I see what you're trying to do.. working on it. I've got this task: `msg: "Password is {{ mypasswordfile['content'] | b64decode | regex_findall('\bpassword\b') }}"`.  It prints`Password is []`

Comment: I just edited it with a fix.  Basically, `regex_findall()` returns an list so it's necessary to grab the first (and only) item.

Answer (score 5):

If the file is local to the ansible system you can use the [ini lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/ini.html) which will read in values from a ini style file.  If your file is remote you can use fetch/slurp to pull a copy to the local system.

I would guess the lookup would be something like

```
- debug: msg="Password is {{ lookup('ini', 'password section=client file=my.cnf') }}"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really close. It's printing `"msg": "Password is vRkfmDfYX2g3wXYt"` which isn't actually the password. Tried `| b64decode` on it but made it worse. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hrm, I might try using the lookup against a different attribute to see if you can look up the user/host or something.

Comment: Try `{{  lookup('ini', 'password section=client file=my.cnf') | password_hash('sha512') }}` for input into the user module.

The password from the file is not encoded, it's plaintext.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command or shell module and do it with awk/sed, someting like:

```
- name: get the value in the block on the file
  command: >
         awk -F ' *= *' '{ if ($1 ~ /^\[/) section=$1;
         else if ($1 ~ /^password/ && section ~ /^\[client\]$/ ) print $2 }'
         "{{ file_path }}"
  register: password_value
```

In this case to handle a comment in the same line you can do

```
- name: setting the password without comments
  set_fact:
    password: "{{ password_value.stdout.split('#')[0] }}"
```